# Define alias for Python module within that module

Tags: python

Is there a way to define an **alias for a module** within that module itself and is it a good idea to do so?

For example, if we have a module `some_looooooooong_name` and would like to allow users to use `slm` as an alias such that even if they just import it as

```
import some_looooooooong_name
```

They can still use `slm.name`. Is that possible and OK to do?

Comment: Why can't users `import some_looooooooong_name as slm` if they want to?

Comment: You can't make your module add itself as another name to the namespace of the module that imports it; nor would it be appropriate if you could. It is up to the script that imports it to use an alias if they want to.

Comment: The scenario I'm trying to handle is that the source code that uses the module `some_looooooooong_name` is auto-generated, and it would be easier to read the code if it's generated as `slm.` instead. The problem is, I don't want to generate the import statement as well, since there would be multiple places where imports might be generated and the code won't look good, which is why it would be easier if the module itself has an alias.

Answer (score 0):

use `as` :)

```py
import some_looooooooong_name as module
from some_looooooooong_name import function_with_long_name as func

print(name.do_something())
print(func())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is that I need a way to alias it inside the module iteslf, so that the user doesn't have to alias it this way.

Comment: @anirudh you cannot do that, and it's a good thing (for a similar reason, it's considered a bad practice to write `from module import *`).